# System.ServiceModel, portable class libraries, and code analysis

Tags: .net, wcf

I've got an interface in a portable class library with code analysis on build enabled.  When I mark it with ServceContract and OperationContract for a WCF service, it starts throwing build errors from code analysis.

```
Assembly reference cannot be resolved: System.ServiceModel, Version=2.0.5.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, Retargetable=Yes
```

The library is targeting .Net 4.5 and Silverlight 5.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think that the portable subset uses an old version of the framework.  Code analysis tries to use the latest version and you end up with this error.  Try FxCop.  This is just a warning there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was related to the compile targets. I had mixed configurations (some libraries in ARM, some in Any CPU). For PCLs Any CPU is almost always the best option.

Comment: Were you able to fix this by switching the just PCL to Any CPU, or did it have to be the entire solution?

Comment: Just the project. I do not remember the exact configuration, since I've done radical changes to the project structure since, but I remember I just changed the platform targets.